# Two Symbol Math

Tags: code-golf, string, arithmetic, balanced-string

## Introduction

The four basic math operators (+, -, *, /) can be reduced to just two, due to the fact that:

```
x + y = x - (-y)
x * y = x / (1/y), y != 0
x * 0 = 0/x
```

## Challenge

The challenge is to take input as a "string" containing:

- Numbers
- Single character variables ("x", "y")
- The four basic math operators (+, -, *, /)
- Parenthesis

and output a string manipulated so that it would produce the same mathematical result as the input, but containing only the mathematical symbols '-' and '/'

## Specifics

- Input can be in any acceptable form (file, STDIN, etc.) and may be represented as a string or character array (but not an array of arrays)
- Output can be in any acceptable form (file, STDIN, etc.) and may be represented as a string or character array (but not an array of arrays)
- You must recognize and maintain balanced parenthesis
- Standard loopholes are disallowed
- It is your choice if you want to represent `x + y` as `x - -y` or `x - (-y)`
- You must maintain the order of operations
- You never have to handle invalid input
- Input can be empty or a single number/variable, in that case the program should output the input
- Note: You **do not** have to use the substitutions in the introduction, so long as `input = output`, your program could change `2 * 2` to `8/2`, if you wanted
- You can assume that "0" is the only way a zero will appear in the equation (I.e. you don't have to handle `1 * (4 - 4)`)
- Suggestion: to test your program, go to [this website](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) type in `input = output`, where input is the input, and output is the output, and if the result is "true" your program handled that case successfully ([example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+*+y+%3D+x+%2F+(1%2Fy)), [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2B%20(x%20*%204)%20-%20(512%20*%203)%20%3D%201%20-%20(-(x%20%2F%20(1%2F4)))%20-%20(512%20%2F%20(1%2F3))))

## Test Cases

Below are some test cases, input as a single string and output as a single string.

```
x + y
x - (-y)

x * y
x / (1/y)

x / y
x / y

x - y
x - y

1
1

5
5

-6
-6

+x
x

1 + (x * 4) - (512 * 3)
1 - (-(x / (1/4))) - (512 / (1/3))

1 - 3 / 4 + l / g
1 - 3/4 - (-(l / g))

5 * 0 / 2
0/5 / 2

(a + g) * 0
0/(a - (-g))
```

## Scoring

It's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins. Ties are resolved by first-post.

Comment: By the way `x / 1/y` = `x/y` because division isn't associative. I know what you're thinking, but even [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%2F+1%2Fy) doesn't recognize that you want spaces to change the order of operations.... so you probably should rethink this or not cite that as a valid way to check things.

Comment: @Linus: It also isn't equivalent when `y=0`, but I'm guessing the challenge implicitly assumes that `n/d => d != 0`.

Comment: @TimČas ahh! Didn't think of that. I'll update the challenge, just know it will have to be handled properly

Comment: As it stands, there's very little stopping us from simply evaluating the expression and returning the result (they're mathematically equal, after all).  I'd recommend changing that, unless you want `v` to be a proper solution in Pyth.

Comment: Wait, so if there are variables (like x and y), how can we divide without risking division by zero? `5 * (a - b)` if a=b. And do we have to detect things like `5 * (a - a)`? How about `5 * (4 - 4)` and `5 * (a / a - 1)` or `5 * (4 / 4 - 1)`?

Comment: @Adam you only have to handle "0" itself, I'll update the challenge

Comment: Can we assume that there will be no spaces in the input or do we have to strip them?

Comment: @BetaDecay handle them... But they're not required in output.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 267 bytes

Thanks to @ConorO'Brien

```py
import re
q=re.sub
g=lambda m:'--'+m.group()[1:]
h=lambda m:'/(1/'+m.group()[1:]+')'
i=lambda m:'0/'+m.group()[:-2]
print(q(r'\*[^\(\)]+',h,q(r'[^\(\)]\*0',i,q(r'\+[^\(\)]+',g,q(r'\*\([^\)]+\)',h,q(r'\([^\)]+\)\*0',i,q(r'\+\([^\)]+\)',g,input().replace(' ',''))))))))
```

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/v67gZI)

Comment: Honestly, I've no idea what dark magic you've employed, but +1 for FGITW

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix Haha the dark magic is called regex ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 42 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

This maintains APLs order of operations. Note that `÷x` is `1÷x`

```apl
'\+' '×'⎕R'--' '÷÷'('(.*)×0'⎕R'0÷\1'~∘' ')
```

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%27%5C+%27%20%27%D7%27%u2395R%27--%27%20%27%F7%F7%27%28%27%28.*%29%D70%27%u2395R%270%F7%5C1%27%7E%u2218%27%20%27%29%20%u22C4%20f%A8%27x%20+%20y%27%20%27x%20%D7%20y%27%20%27x%20%F7%20y%27%20%27x%20-%20y%27%20%271%27%20%275%27%20%27-6%27%20%27+x%27%20%271%20+%20%28x%20%D7%204%29%20-%20%28512%20%D7%203%29%27%20%271%20-%203%20%F7%204%20+%20l%20%F7%20g%27%20%275%20%D7%200%20%F7%202%27%20%27%28a%20+%20g%29%20%D7%200%27&run)

`(` on the result of...

`~∘' '` remove spaces

`'(.*)×0'⎕R'0÷\1'` replace anything followed by "×0" with "0÷" followed by it

`)` evaluate...

`'\+' '×'⎕R'--' '÷÷'` replace "+" with "--" and "×" with "÷÷"

#### To verify:

1. [Assign random non-zero numbers to `x`, `y`, `l`, `g`, and `a`.](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u22A2x%20y%20l%20g%20a%u21905%3F9&run)
2. [Execute the original expressions.](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28x%20+%20y%29%28x%20%D7%20y%29%28x%20%F7%20y%29%28x%20-%20y%29%281%29%285%29%28-6%29%28+x%29%281%20+%20%28x%20%D7%204%29%20-%20%28512%20%D7%203%29%29%281%20-%203%20%F7%204%20+%20l%20%F7%20g%29%285%20%D7%200%20%F7%202%29%28%28a%20+%20g%29%20%D7%200%29&run)
3. [Execute the modified expressions.](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28x--y%29%28x%F7%F7y%29%28x%F7y%29%28x-y%29%281%29%285%29%28-6%29%28--x%29%281--%28x%F7%F74%29-%28512%F7%F73%29%29%281-3%F74--l%F7g%29%280%F75%F72%29%280%F7%28a--g%29%29&run)
4. [Compare the results.](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28x%20+%20y%29%28x%20%D7%20y%29%28x%20%F7%20y%29%28x%20-%20y%29%281%29%285%29%28-6%29%28+x%29%281%20+%20%28x%20%D7%204%29%20-%20%28512%20%D7%203%29%29%281%20-%203%20%F7%204%20+%20l%20%F7%20g%29%285%20%D7%200%20%F7%202%29%28%28a%20+%20g%29%20%D7%200%29%u2261%28x--y%29%28x%F7%F7y%29%28x%F7y%29%28x-y%29%281%29%285%29%28-6%29%28--x%29%281--%28x%F7%F74%29-%28512%F7%F73%29%29%281-3%F74--l%F7g%29%280%F75%F72%29%280%F7%28a--g%29%29&run)

Answer (score 0):

## SED <strike>272 246 239</strike> 213

```
s,^\+,,;s,[^+*/()-]\+,(&),g;t;:;s,)[^)]*)\*(0,&,;tr;s,\((.*)\)\*(0),(0/\1),;ty;s,\*([^)]*(,&,;tr;s,\*\(([^)]*)\),/(1/\1),;ty;s,\+([^)]*(,&,;tr;s,\+\(([^)]*)\),-(-\1),;ty;p;q;:r;s,(\([^()]*\)),!\1@,;t;:y;y,!@,(),;b
```

Take input without spaces (e.g. `x+y*2`).
This is one of the few cases where it is actually shorter to just escape `(` and `)` for capture groups instead of using `-r`. I'm sure this can be golfed more, but I'm happy for now.

Ungolfed, with comments:

```
s,^\+,, #remove leading +
s,[^+*/()-]\+,(&),g #suround numbers/variables in ()
t start #reset the test because the line above will always match

:start
#------------- deal with *0 ------------------
s,)[^)]*)\*(0,&, #remove inner matching ()
t replace
s,\((.*)\)\*(0),(0/\1),
t y
#------------- deal with generic * -----------
s,\*([^)]*(,&, #remove inner matching ()
t replace
s,\*\(([^)]*)\),/(1/\1),
t y
#------------- deal with + -------------------
s,\+([^)]*(,&, #remove inner matching ()
t replace
s,\+\(([^)]*)\),-(-\1),
t y

b end #all done, branch to the end

#------------- replace a set of () with !@ ---
#repeated application of this helps find the matching ( or )
:replace
s,(\([^()]*\)),!\1@,
t start

:y
y,!@,(),
b start

:end
```